# ReactNative Retrive Data from Firebase to RecyclerListView

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to get The RecyclerListView to display the data i get from firebase.

but i get error

> undefined isn't an object (evaluating this.state.dataProvider.cloneWithRows)

here is my code

```
        constructor(props) {
          super(props)
          const categories = [];
          firebase.database().ref('category/' + this.props.navigation.getParam('category')).orderByChild('ratingCount').on('value', (snap) => {    
             snap.forEach((child) => {
              categories.push({
                type: 'NORMAL',
                item:{
                 id: child.val().id,
                 name: child.val().name,
                 description: child.val().rating,
                }
             });
             });

          alert(JSON.stringify(categories));

             this.setState({
               list: this.state.dataProvider.cloneWithRows(categories)
             });
           });

          this.state = { 
             list: new DataProvider((r1, r2) => {
                return r1 !== r2;
              })
          };

          this.layoutProvider = new LayoutProvider((i) => {
             return this.state.list.getDataForIndex(i).type;
           }, (type, dim) => {
             switch (type) {
               case 'NORMAL': 
                 dim.width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
                 dim.height = 100;
                 break;
               default: 
                 dim.width = 0;
                 dim.height = 0;
                 break;
             };
           })
        }

        rowRenderer = (type, data) => {
          const { name, description } = data.item;
          //i know im not displaying anydata here will when it work
        }
  render() {
        return (                                                                                                           
                <RecyclerListView
                style={{flex: 1, minHeight: 1, minWidth: 1,}}
             rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
             dataProvider={this.state.list}
             layoutProvider={this.layoutProvider}
                />     
       );                                                                                                                 
    }
```

here is what alert(JSON.stringify(categories)) do

> [{"type":"NORMAL","item":{"id":0,"name":"Mahmoud Photography","description":4}},{"type":"NORMAL","item":{"id":1,"name":"Ahmed Photography","description":5}}]

what am i doing wrong ? the RecyclerListView package is somehow similar to ListView if anyone can help :)

Comment: This is natural for you to have no dataProvider status value.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand can you explain more cuz im stuck with this problem for days :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is natural for you to have no `dataProvider` status value.

`this.state` is To set the initial value: `this.state={ dataProvider: data }` or `state={ dataProvider: data }`

And the `dataProvider` type of `RecyclerListView` is `dataProvider`.

So you can try this

```js
let dataProvider = new DataProvider((r1, r2) => {
            return r1 !== r2;
        });
...
this.state = {
            list: dataProvider.cloneWithRows(categories)
        };
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. i tried it but i got null isn't an object (evaluating'this.state.list')

Comment: Does your error occur when creating LayoutProvider?

Comment: it works when i set the `            ``const categories = [{"type":"NORMAL","item":{"id":0,"name":"Mahmoud Photography","description":4}},{"type":"NORMAL","item":{"id":1,"name":"Ahmed Photography","description":5}}];``
`
like this but i can't display the items from firebase directly